# Is it possible to not create output zip if there are no files in specified paths when using grunt-contrib-compress?

Tags: gruntjs, compression, grunt-contrib-compress

I have this target:

```
module.exports = function (grunt, config) {
  var path = require('path'),
    zipOutputPath = /*getOutputPath*/,
    someOptions = /*getOptions*/;

  return {
    options: someOptions,
    myTarget: {
      options: {
        archive: zipOutputPath + path.join + 'zipName.zip'
      },
      files: [
        {
          src: ['test-reports/**']
        },
        {
          src: ['*.xml']
        }
      ]
    }
  };
};
```

Imagine there are no files in `test-reports/**` path and no `xml` files in cwd. In this after running `grunt compress:myTarget` `grunt-contrib-compress` will create **empty** zip archive with name `zipName` at `zipOutputPath`.

Is it somehow possible to not create zip archive if there were no files in specified places? Maybe there is some option or any workaround available?

Comment: You can probably try this [npm glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to get the length of your `src`, the apply the grunt-contrib-compress if it's not `0`